# Is there a way to check whether gtk.flowbox is empty?

Tags: gtk

This is related to an issue I'm trying to solve in a project. The latter is using `invalidate_filter` to keep the contents updated with a searching function. However if the searched keyword doesn't exist, an empty flowbox is returned. I'm trying to find a way to check whether flowbox is empty but there doesn't seem to be any function for that. Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

To see if a flowbox is empty, you can get the first child of a flowbox with `gtk_flow_box_get_child_at_index (flowbox, 0)` and see if it's NULL.